# custom facebook like button and callback function after like action

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

i am trying to make the custom fb like button in angular js. So that i can call service to save some data for analytics purpose.we have to keep the track of the number of like of my page in our database.

Comment: You can not make a custom like button, you can only use the official Like Button plugin. If you need to know when users created or deleted a like using that button, you can subscribe to the events the JS SDK provides for that purpose. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.8